# How Do I Change the Background Color of a Tab Icon (Material Bottom Tabs, React Navigation 6)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I'm very new to React Native and everything I know is from fairly outdated courses or tutorials. I'm currently working on a personal project (Expo managed) with some pretty specific styling, but I'm having an issue in particular changing the background color of my tab bar icons, which are, by default, this sort of lavender color (see below). I don't know if I've missed something very important in the Documentation, but I can't seem to find a solution to this. How can I change this within my current code? I've considered looking to React Native Paper for solutions, but didn't want to over-complicate things for myself just yet. Hopefully somebody can help!

[Tab icon background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut99O.png)

```
import React from 'react';

import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import NewsNavigation from './News/NewsNavigation';
import EventNavigation from './Events/EventNavigation';
import VotingScreen from '../../screens/Home/Voting/VotingScreen'
import AccountScreen from '../../screens/Home/User/AccountScreen'
import BadgeScreen from '../../screens/Home/Badges/BadgeScreen'

import { FontAwesome, FontAwesome5, MaterialCommunityIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const MainTabNavigation = () => {
    return(
        <Tab.Navigator 
            barStyle={{ 
                backgroundColor: '#323b4b', 
                borderTopWidth: 2, 
                borderTopColor: '#ff9f2e',
                height: 75,
            }}
            activeColor='#ff9f2e'
            inactiveColor='white'
        >
            <Tab.Screen 
                name='News' 
                component={NewsNavigation} 
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: (({color}) => (
                        <FontAwesome 
                            name='newspaper-o' 
                            style={[styles.tabBarIcon, {color}]}
                        />
                    ))
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen 
                name='Events' 
                component={EventNavigation} 
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: (({color}) => (
                        <FontAwesome 
                            name='users' //calendar also a good choice
                            style={[styles.tabBarIcon, {color}]}
                        />
                    ))
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen 
                name='Voting' 
                component={VotingScreen} 
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: (({color}) => (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons 
                            name='vote-outline' 
                            style={[styles.tabBarIcon, {fontSize: 25, top: 0, color}]}
                        />
                    ))
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen 
                name='Badges' 
                component={BadgeScreen} 
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: (({color}) => (
                        <FontAwesome5 
                            name='medal' 
                            style={[styles.tabBarIcon, {color}]}
                        />
                    ))
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen 
                name='Account' 
                component={AccountScreen} 
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: (({color}) => (
                        <FontAwesome 
                            name='user' 
                            style={[styles.tabBarIcon, {color}]}
                        />
                    ))
                }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    tabBarIcon: {
        fontSize: 20,
        top: 2
    }
})

export default MainTabNavigation;
```

I've tried:

- Consulting the documentation
- Looking at other examples
- Playing with different props and settings
- Chanting incantations in hopes one of the React Native fairies can fix it for me

I have been unable to get access to an ios device or emulator, so all issues are based on Android streaming and emulation.